# Documentation of lmodern package?

Tags: fonts, documentation

Recently I have faced some problems with `lmodern` package.

I wanted to read the documentation to educate myself of possible parameters that can be specified when using the package, and what I can do with it later.

However, after spending some time on google I couldn't find it.

I only found:

- An interesting *article* about lmodern (http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/robertson/robertson.pdf). While interesting and useful it probably does not cover everything.
- a CTAN folder, but it didn't contain a documentation either (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lmodern)

Where can I find full documentation for the `lmodern` package?

Comment: http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/lm/doc/fonts/lm/lm-info.pdf provides documentation of the fonts. As egreg says, there is not much to say about use of the package as it provides only the three options mentioned in his answer. However, http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/lm/doc/fonts/lm contains various sample `.tex` files and what documentation there is. You don't say which problems you encountered so it is a bit difficult to say how you might solve them.

Comment: My concrete problem was that `\ttfamily` supported `\itshape`, but `\bfseries` was barely different, while when using `[lighttt]`, `\bfseries` was nicely visible but trying `\itshape` resulted in an error. I was hoping the documentation would explain what works with what and how I can combine the lighttt with non-lighttt within a single document. After digging into robertson's article I managed to solve it, but was expecting to find a lmodern documentation somewhere...

Comment: I hesitate to suggest this but `cfr-lm` includes commands which make it easy to switch weights mid-document. This includes the light weight of the `tt` fonts. Of course, there may be other reasons not to use my package but it does do that much. (And it does have documentation explaining this.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's not much to say. The package can be passed three options:

- `nomath`, which will not change the math fonts, keeping the default Computer Modern;
- `variablett`, that sets up a variable width typewriter font;
- `lighttt`, that uses a lighter version of the typewriter font, so the bold variant is more evident.

The main action of the package is to set up text fonts so that the Latin Modern family is used.

Answer (score 3):

You have this in lmodern.sty:

```
% This file belongs to the Latin Modern package. The work is released
% under the GUST Font License. See the MANIFEST-Latin-Modern.txt and
% README-Latin-Modern.txt files for the details. For the most recent version of
% this license see http://www.gust.org.pl/fonts/licenses/GUST-FONT-LICENSE.txt
% or http://tug.org/fonts/licenses/GUST-FONT-LICENSE.txt
```

So readme after using google:

http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/download/readme-latin-modern.txt/view

Comment: That readme is not really a documentation of how to use the package.