# \big parenthesis not much bigger than simple parenthesis in 11pt font

Tags: math-mode, macros, fontsize, brackets

I frequently use simple and larger parenthesis in math mode, like what is shown in the MWE below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\bigs}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{1.25}{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

Blabla bla bla blabla :
    \begin{equation}
        \Big( c \, \bigs( \big( (1 + (x - y^2)(a + b) \big) \bigs) \Big) = \tfrac{3}{4}.
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I usually don't use the `\left \right` variants, since I find them too big, and also for other reasons that aren't relevant here.

The `\big( \big)` commands give a nice output when the document is written in 12pt size.  The difference with simple `()` is clear.  But then, If I reduce the font to 11pt, the difference becomes very small, almost negligible.  Why is that?

To solve this, I defined a small macro to give something between the simple parenthesis and the `\Big` version.  But I'm now wondering why I have to do this and if this a proper way of doing things in LaTeX.

Comment: unrelated to the size question but you should not use `\big` or `\Big` etc in a document they are just the internal implementation of code shared between `\big;` and `\bigr`, it should be `\Bigl(....\Bigr)`

Comment: I don't see any differences using \bigl and \bigr, and they make typing a bit longer.

Comment: The horizontal spacing is incorrect. `\Big(` is a mathord, `\Bigl(` is a mathopen.

Comment: I don't see any horizontal difference (from the MWE above).  Maybe that example isn't complicated enough?  And what is a mathord?

Comment: \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\sin{(}x{)}  \rightarrow \sin(x)$

$\sin\big(x\big) \rightarrow \sin\bigl(x\bigr)$


\end{document}

Comment: That's in text mode (I mean inside a text line).

Comment: I see the difference.  But then, If I use {} for the trig functions, the spacing troubles is back.  For example: **\sin{\bigl( x \bigr)}**.  I usually put the trig argument inside {}.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the last comment, but `\big` is simply wrong always, it may accidentally give the same spacing because a mathord and mathopen get the same space in some contexts but it is not supported document markup.

Comment: putting the argument in `{}` destroys the spacing, why are you using braces?

Comment: Because trig functions have an argument.

Comment: that isn't a reason for forcing tex to lose its classification of math constructs and so badly space the expression. The mathematical function has an argument but the tex command `\sin` does not so the braces are not absorbed by `\sin` as an argument, they instead coerce the `(...)` to start with a mathord not a mathopen,

Comment: Hmm, then I'll have a nightmare in fixing my book.  There are thousands of trig functions in there, using {} !

Comment: But then this isn't solving the size issue with **\bigl( \bigr)**, compared to () and **\Bigl( \Bigr)**.

Comment: Q: "Why are you using braces?" A: "Because trig functions have an argument." Not in TeX and LaTeX! The correct syntax is `$\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)$`. Note that `$\sin{(\theta_1)}$` inserts too much whitespace between "sin" and "(" -- and is thus wrong from a *typographic* perspective.

Comment: Issues about spacing aside (just to be clear: I agree with David and Mico) your issue is due to an unfortunate setting of the `lmodern` fonts. If you comment out `lmodern` you'll see that the `\big` parentheses are in fact larger. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137143/82917 (slightly different question but same reason)

Comment: @Cham The problem is indeed the same as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137141/4427 I'd close this one as duplicate, what do you think?

Comment: @campa, wow, now it's the font!  Thanks a lot.  Yep, you may mark my question as a duplicate.

Comment: According to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175605/documentation-of-lmodern-package, a solution is to add an option to the **lmodern** package: **\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}**.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is the **lmodern** font used.  A solution is to add an option to that font by loading it with a **nomath** option (see the answer to this question: [Documentation of lmodern package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175605/documentation-of-lmodern-package)):

```
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
```

However, I'm now wondering about the values of the **lmodern** font.  Why use it?  What are its differences with the default *computer modern*?  I don't see much differences, except for the integral signs (size again).  About these fonts:

[Is it still useful to load the lmodern package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147194/is-it-still-useful-to-load-the-lmodern-package)