# How to properly compiler LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex

I recently installed LuaLaTeX and I want to change the font. I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/243486/233346) answer on this site describing different ways to include fonts and with which flavors of TeX they should work with.

I have reproduced the first example below, which according to the answer should work with pdflatex and lualatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\sffamily
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

However, the second lines appears the same for me (no change in font) when I use lualatex.

I have been compiling with `pdflatex test.tex` and `lualatex test.tex`. Am I missing an option for lualatex that will help with the font? When I compile with `lualatex` I get the following warning.

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/cmbr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 7.
```

I also went ahead and installed `texlive-full` just to be sure I wasn't missing some font package, but I still get the same warning and consequently no change in font.

Comment: Probably something changed. Documentation a bit hard to find but I can find [fonts - Documentation of lmodern package? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175605/documentation-of-lmodern-package) && `texdoc fntguide` which explains what `sfdefault` do, then find `cmbr` is the family name for the "computer modern bright" font. Meanwhile `\usepackage{cmbright}` gives an error...

Comment: That package should be installed in TeX live ([texlive - What font packages are installed in TeX live? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59403/what-font-packages-are-installed-in-tex-live)). Depends on what operating system you're using, figure out ways to install `cmbright` package e.g. on some Linux distribution I think you need to install `texlive-fontsextra` package.

Comment: The answer you found is 8 years old and now no longer true. LaTeX has adapted the default font encoding for the unicode engines to TU in the meantime.

Comment: Got it, I will switch back to including `\usepackage[T1]{fontspec}`. Is there a benefit to the TU encoding? I did a quick google search on it, but I could not find much information.